# Eloquent casting attributes to Collections unexpected behaviour

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.4

**Q1.** I have an Eloquent model that casts an attribute to a Collection.
Calling Collection's method on this attribute doesn't affect the model values. Eg: `put()`

When using Collections , iam able to do this :

```
$var = collect();
$var->put('ip', '127.0.0.1');
var_dump($var);
```

Output as expected :

`object(Illuminate\Support\Collection)[191]
  protected 'items' => 
    array (size=1)
      'ip' => string '127.0.0.1' (length=4)`

But when i use with a casted attribute on a Eloquent model, this doesn't work as expected

```
$user = App\User::create(['email'=>'Name', 'email'=>'mail@example.com', 'password'=>bcrypt('1234')]);
$user->properties = collect();
$user->properties->put('ip', '127.0.0.1');
var_dump($user->properties);
```

`object(Illuminate\Support\Collection)[201]
  protected 'items' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty`

This doesn't populate the field.
I think that another collection is created, so to work as expected i must assign this new collection to my field.

Like so :
`$user->properties = $user->properties->put('ip', '127.0.0.1');`

**Q2.** Is there a proper way to initialize collection of the field by default (create an empty collection if the field is null), without having to call `$user->properties = collect();` "manually" every time?

---

*User.php*

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $casts = [
        'properties' => 'collection',
    ];
    ...
}
```

*Migration file*

```
Schema::table('users', function($table) {
    $table->text('properties')->nullable();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Q1**: an attribute casted to collection has a *getter* that returns, **each time**, a `new BaseCollection` that is constructed on the value of the attribute.

As already supposed the getter returns **another** collection instance and every direct change on it **does not change** the value of the *attribute* but instead the newly created collection object.

As also pointed by you the only way to set a a collection casted attribute is to assign it his own original value merged with new ones.

So instead of `put()` you have to use:

```
$user->properties = $user->properties->put('ip', '127.0.0.1');
// or
$user->properties = $user->properties ->merge(['ip'=>'127.0.0.1'])
```

**Q2**: We have to think that the database representation is a **text**; so IMHO the proper way to initialize a **Model** in the *migration* is to give it a default *empty json*, i.e.:

```
$table->text('properties')->default('{}');
```

But this works **only** for models created without setting the property field and **retrieved after**.

For a *newly created* **Model** my advice is to pass a default `void array`, i.e.:

```
 App\User::create([
     'name'=>'Name', 
     'email'=>'mail@example.com', 
     'password'=>bcrypt('1234'),
     'properties' => []
 ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to dparoli's outstanding answer, it is also possible to add a default value through Laravel's boot method, which is available on every Model.

Something like the following **example** code

```
   protected static function boot()
   {
      parent::boot(); //because we want the parent boot to be run as well
      static::creating(function($model){
         $model->propertyName = 'propertyValue';
      });
    }
```

You can play with this approach if you like as well.